# What error would cause rails to redirect back to the form and not write to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called Template Controller, generated from a scaffold and it saves a simple template model to a mongo database, and for some reason I keep getting this problem: When I go to save in the template/new view, it doesn't save to the database, returning a 'Review the problems below" (in the style as if I had left something blank). Sorry if I've left out any important info, let me know if I need anything else. I've been stumped on this one for hours today!

**Here is a sample of the log:**

`Processing by TemplatesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MnV8IoD92XSAGA2pUZr2PXwO/os8bgm/4ouT7baT+hA=", "template"=>{"task_name"=>"10", "task_type"=>"calls", "number_to_complete"=>"10", "description"=>"10"}, "commit"=>"Create Template"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=local collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"52e16f81bd9eb69d4a000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7575ms)
  Rendered templates/_form.html.haml (19.0ms)
  Rendered templates/new.html.haml within layouts/application (21.6ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=local collection=organizations selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"52c6d7daf13b975c79000002"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.3543ms)
Completed 200 OK in 229.4ms (Views: 219.6ms)`

**My model:**

```
class Template < Task
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
field :task_name, type: String
field :task_type, type: String
field :number_to_complete, type: Integer
field :description, type: String
field :id, type: Integer
attr_accessible :about_attributes, :task_name, :task_type, :number_to_complete, :description, :id

end
```

**And the controller:**

```
class TemplatesController < InheritedResources::Base
def new
@template = Template.new
@task_types = Task.task_type
end
end
```

Comment: In the view try `<%= @template.errors.full_messages %>`. That should show you any validation errors which would be hidden otherwise.

Comment: Can you share the `create` action of `TemplatesController`.

Comment: Daniel - I'll try that, thanks! I've been trying to figure out how to get an in depth log.
Kirti - How would I go about that? I generated from a scaffold, and I have no idea how to see what InheritedResources::base does for the create action.

Comment: OH WOW okay thanks Daniel - I had forgotten that the template model was inheriting another model, so it was whining about leaving fields blank that I had set as required in the parent model. If you leave that as an answer I'll mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know which validation errors prevent saving of a model, you have to output them somehow.

A quick and dirty solution:

```
<%= @template.errors.full_messages.join(', ') %>
```

But except for simple debugging purposes it would be better to provide more sophisticated feedback, for example by highlighting the invalid input fields and displaying the errors beneath.